# Is there a back-port of pack200 on pre-1.5 jre?

Tags: java, backwards-compatibility

Is there a library or add-on for **pre-1.5 JRE** (1.3 or 1.4) that can *uncompress and run* pack200-packed JARs?

EDIT:

I need this because I'm writing an applet for a legacy Java 1.3 environment, and I want to save bandwidth by compressing the jar as much as possible.

Comment: Why are you coding to support obsolete JREs?

Comment: Because I'm writing [kiosk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Use_Self_Service) software, which requires jre 1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't.  However, that is only part of your problem.

There is a high likelihood that the contents of the pack200 archive were compiled with JDK 1.6.  Even if you could chain in the decompression of the pack200 archive into the class loader, odds are excellent that then your JVM would be complaining that it can't understand these version 1.6 compiled class files (because that version was penned AFTER the 1.5 JVM was released).

Now, if you are guaranteeing that the contents are JRE 1.5 compatible, then if you really want to use pack200 (or some other better compressing archive file format), you'll have to work in your own custom `ClassLoader`, which will give you full control over finding the classes.  That will allow you to uncompress the archive and search it during class look ups.

Unless this is a key feature of your software, odds are excellent that you should stick to delivering JAR files for 1.5.

Comment: The likelihood that the contents of the pack200 archive were compiled with JDK 1.6 is zero. These are my own 1.3 class files which I want to compress to save bandwidth.

Comment: Oh, and I need to be able to run in a sandbox. Can I use my own ClassLoader in an applet?

Comment: *"Can I use my own ClassLoader in an applet?"* Not in a sand-boxed applet, no.

Comment: Although I did see some open-source pack200 code in the Harmony and OpenJDK projects, I'm going to accept this answer, because making it work in an sandboxed applet environment seems to be impossible.

Comment: @rustyx, sorry to hear it, but a sandboxed applet is really using someone else's machine, and if you use someone else's machine, you must tolerate the means used to keep that machine from being exploited (even if you don't intend to exploit it).  Altering the classloader opens up lots of opportunities for misuse.  That's why it is denied to all who don't actually control the machine.  Might look into some of the non-default zip compression to see if they work / are smaller.